# nextjs on aws Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

Facing this error for about 6 hours of trial and error.  Between search, bard and chatgpt; I cannot find an answer.  Getting a 403 error.  Appears to be on the S3 bucket--however Amplify manages this so the related buckets do not appear on my S3 page in the console.   I have tried the recommended answer using terraform:

```
`custom_rule {
source = "/<*>"
target  = "/index.html"
status = 200
}`
```

The build and deploy are successful.  I can't figure this one out...

[image: 403 error]